# How to index all the properties while uploading them to the GAE datastore (Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a use case where I have a large amount of data that will be stored on the GAE datastore. Therefore, I need to index all the properties when they are inserted in the datastore and make the user wait until all the properties are indexed.

I have to perform different querying operations using projection queries for which it is important that all the properties must be indexed. (Referred from the documentation).

To make it clearer I need to perform queries like following:

1. select city,gender from kind where city notequalto 'abc' and gender equalto 'xyz'
2. select gender,city,status from kind where gender notequalto 'xyz' city equalto 'abc' and status equalto 'pqr'
3. select gender from kind where city equalto 'abc' and city equalto 'pqr'

I also need to fetch the distinct values from all the results that is returned.

I searched online, but did not find considerable documentation and support regarding this.

Please advise.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking. Are you asking how to wait for indexing to finish for all inserted data? If so, you can't "wait" for it to finish, but what you're looking for is strong consistency which guarantees to always return the latest version of your data: https://blog.tomtasche.at/2016/06/appengine-101-datastore-consistency.html and https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore